# To count the no. of times a char occur in a string

Tags: java, string

## i have done this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
 int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i1=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0,q=0,r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z = 0;
```

/initialized the variable and counted each matches./

```
    System.out.println("enter the string");
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1=sc.nextLine();
```

/i m taking a string as a i/p from user

```
    int a = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<(s1.length());i++)
    {
        if (s1.charAt(i)=='a')
            
        {
            a++;
        }
         if (s1.charAt(i)=='b')
            
        {
            b++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='c')
            
        {
            c++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='d')
            
        {
            d++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='e')
            
        {
            e++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='f')
            
        {
            f++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='g')
            
        {
            g++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='h')
            
        {
            h++;
        }

        if (s1.charAt(i)=='i')
            
        {
            i1++;
        }            
        if (s1.charAt(i)=='j')
            
        {
            j++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='k')
            
        {
            k++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='l')
            
        {
            l++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='m')
            
        {
            m++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='m')
            
        {
            m++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='n')
            
        {
            n++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='o')
            
        {
            o++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='p')
            
        {
            p++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='q')
            
        {
            q++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='r')
            
        {
            r++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='s')
            
        {
            s++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='t')
            
        {
            t++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='u')
            
        {
            u++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='v')
            
        {
            v++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='w')
            
        {
            w++;
        }
         if (s1.charAt(i)=='x')
            
        {
            x++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='y')
            
        {
            y++;
        } if (s1.charAt(i)=='z')
            
        {
            z++;
        }
  
  /...................................adkjagkdgakjdjakdjg/
       
          }
```

but its not possible to write whole 26 variables again again for printing also...please sugeest me some another option.

Comment: use a `Map<Character c ,Integer count>`

Comment: search [here](http://www.google.com)

Comment: You code only counts lowercase letters.  What about uppercase, digits, spaces, punctuations?  That is why you should use a Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use a `Map`.

For instance:

```
System.out.println("enter the string");
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
String s1=sc.nextLine();
if (s1 != null && !s1.isEmpty()) {
    // will display character counts alphabetically
    Map<Character, Integer> count = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] chars = s1.toCharArray();
    for (char c: chars) {
        // no count yet for this character
        if (count.get(c) == null) {
            count.put(c,  1);
        }
        // this character appeared at least once: incrementing count
        else {
            count.put(c,  count.get(c) + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

**Output**

```
enter the string
abcdeff
{a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1, f=2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use `int` array of `26` elements. Let us initialize the array of 26 elements:-

```
int[] array=new int[26];
```

Now it can be considered that `0th` element is `a` , `1st` element is `b` and so on. Now suppose we have string `str`. Now iterating string to its end.

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    array[str.charAt(i)-'a']++;    //Storing occurrence of characters in array
}
```

Now we have occurrence of characters in array and just iterate over `array` get all value's print.

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    char ch=(char)('a'+i);
    System.out.println(ch+":"+array[i]);
}
```

Or if you want to print only occurring characters:-

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    char ch=(char)('a'+i);
    if(array[i]>0)
    System.out.println(ch+":"+array[i]);
}
```

Comment: why do you want to print the char which does not exists!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `Map`

```
String str = "occurrences";
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 for (char i : str.toCharArray()) {
    Integer value = map.get(i + "");
      if (value != null) {
         map.put(i + "", value + 1);
      } else {
         map.put(i + "", 1);
      }
 }
```

System.out.println(map);

Out put:

```
{u=1, e=2, s=1, r=2, c=3, n=1, o=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, if you want to associate a unique key with a value (in your case, a character and its number of occurrences) a `Map<Character,Integer>` is the correct choice.

There are a number of website that teach you about using maps out there. [Here's one for starters](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/using_4.shtml). I won't spoon feed you the code, since you are clearly trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>;  

 for(int i=0;i<(s1.length());i++)
 {
  Integer count = charCountMap(s1.charAt(i));
   if(count == null){
     charCountMap.put(1);
   } else {
     charCountMap.put(++count);
   }
 }
```

To get number of occurences of a:

```
 int count = charCountMap.get('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ascii values to achieve that.

```
    String s;

    int[] arr = new int[26];

    for(char x : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        arr[x-97]++;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

        System.out.println("Count of "+(char)(97+i)+" :"+arr[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] array = new int[256];
    String str = "sdfdagfvdsgfrewfwqafasfdfa";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        array[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println((char) i + ":" + array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2D array this can do as follows

public class Counter {

```
private String[][] letterArray;

Counter(){
    String letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    letterArray = new String[26][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++){
        letterArray[i] = new String[]{letter.charAt(i)+ "", "0"};
    }
}

void setLetterCount(String sentence){
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        String ch = sentence.charAt(i)+"";
        for(int x = 0; x < letterArray.length; x++){
            String letter = letterArray[x][0].toLowerCase();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(letterArray[x][1].toString());
            if (letter.equals(ch)){
                letterArray[x][1] = ++num+"";
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printLetters(){
    for(String arr[] : letterArray){
        System.out.println(arr[0]+ " : "+ arr[1]);
    }
}
```

}

public class CounterApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    Counter counter = new Counter();

    System.out.print("Enter the sentence : ");
    String sentence=sc.nextLine();

    counter.setLetterCount(sentence);
    counter.printLetters();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without 2D array

public class LetterCounter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the sentence : ");
    String sentence=sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    int arr[] = new int[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        int num = ((int)ch) - 97;
        arr[num] = arr[num] + 1;
    }

    int ch = 97;
    for(int i : arr){
        if(i > 0) {
            System.out.println(((char)ch)+ " : "+ i);
        }
        ch++;
    }

}
```

}